# How to collect Firebase phone verification code without using JavaScript prompt in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

This question is a follow up to the answer here: [Link Phone Number with Facebook and Gmail account in Firebase on Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659141/link-phone-number-with-facebook-and-gmail-account-in-firebase-on-web/48515432#48515432)

In the answer, the SMS code was collected using a prompt. But i would like to know how to collect it using a custom input field.

Thanks.

Comment: post your code so we could help you

Comment: Her's a link to my code: https://gist.github.com/ifeanyidavid/b54387da2b585d33ef3ffd288b0698f1

Answer (score 1):

The use of prompt is just for illustration purposes and not the recommended flow.

```
result.user.linkWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
    .then(function(confirmationResult) {
      // Show your UI where you ask user to input code.
      document.getElementById('codeInputForm').style.display = 'block';
      // Listen to code submit.
      document.getElementById('codeInputSubmit')
          .addEventListener('click', function() {
            // Get code and verify it is not empty.
            var code = document.getElementBydId('smsCode').value;
            if (!code) {
              return;
            }
            // Complete sign-in.
            confirmationResult.confirm(code)
              .then(function(result) {
                // Successful linking.
                gotoSuccessPage();
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                // Handler error;
              });
          })
    })
```