# Firebase how to link account created with phoneNumber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

✅ I am able to let user update their profile with mobile number using `verifyPhoneNumber` and update `currentUser.updatePhoneNumber`

❌ My problem comes when I allow login by phone, and a **NEW USER** tries signing in with a phone number, an account is automatically created.

If I then **need to associate the number with an email account**, the above method will return `credential-already-in-use` error.

Firebase recommends the following method in their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth).

```
var credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(confirmationResult.verificationId, code);

firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
```

So I did this together `linkWithCredential` however, signInWithCredential returns a result with `result.credential = null`

```
// Sign in user with the account you want to link to
auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then(function(result) {
  console.log("Sign In Success", result);
  var currentUser = result.user;

  return prevUser.linkWithCredential(result.credential) //this line doesn't work.
    .then(function(linkResult) {

      return auth.signInWithCredential(linkResult.credential);
    })
}).catch(function(error) {

  console.log("Sign In Error", error);

});
```

Since result.credential = null, I am unable to proceed with LinkWithCredential.

I've also tried `linkWithPhoneNumber`, but it returns a validation ID, which I still cannot merge the account.

❓May I know how did you guys merge a phoneNumber account with other account(Facebook/google/email)?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking is this what you are looking for?

Comment: see my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to link an existing account with a phone number you can use `linkWithPhoneNumber`. Basically you after user sign in (let say with Google), you retrieve user info and then later on link that credential with the phone number. I found a detail answer that is similar to your question [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659141/link-phone-number-with-facebook-and-gmail-account-in-firebase-on-web)

Comment: I've also tried linkWithPhoneNumber, but it returns a validation ID, which I still cannot merge the account. It doesn't return a credential

Comment: but i will give you the bounty anyway for trying.

Comment: What if I want to go the other way round. If I have already created a user with phone Number, how can I link an email address account with it. Can you please help me out with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use auth provider linking:

```
async sendSmsVerification() {
// 'recaptcha-container' is the ID of an element in the DOM.
const applicationVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container')
const provider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider()

const confirmationResult: firebase.auth.ConfirmationResult = await this.userData.linkWithPhoneNumber('+1nnnnn', applicationVerifier)
.catch(error => error)

const verificationCode = window.prompt('Please enter the verification ' +
  'code that was sent to your mobile device.')

  const res = await confirmationResult.confirm(verificationCode)
  .catch(error => error)
  console.log('res', res)

applicationVerifier.clear()

return res  }
```

**res** will tell you if it was successful, the user entered the wrong code or the phone number is already in use.
As a bonus, the user can also login with the phone number now.

You can find more details here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking?authuser=0

Comment: this does not work if the phone number is already a registered account (SMS login)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Something like

```js
const confirmationResult = await firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptcha);
//Prompt your user for the code they recieved via sms here
confirmationResult.confirm(code);
```

where you have a User that has logged in via username/password, facebook google,etc...
would work?

Since you don't get a verification ID from Phone Linking but rather a [ConfirmationResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.ConfirmationResult)

Comment: I've also tried linkWithPhoneNumber, but it returns a validation ID, which I still cannot merge the account.